# How should I go about leveling my bathroom subfloor?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, toilet, subfloor

[image: bracing installed between joists]Over years, after replacing gaskets, replacing the toilet, and using shims under the toilet, I finally began the subfloor replacement in the area beneath the toilet to resolve the toilet not sitting flush and water accumulating outside the toilet base.

However, I learned that a layer of the subfloor is particle board (7/8" actual depth).

The area to drill in screws to toenail bracing against the joists is tight so it's awkward and almost impossible to get the bracing installed level with the joists. Then, cutting and placing the subfloor plywood layers to build it up so it's flush with the surrounding subfloor is resulting in them not being level. It's 1/8" - 1/4" uneven in some spots the floor levels off again ~1ft in front of the toilet.

What's the wisest way and most efficient way to proceed with leveling this so this new subfloor is level with the existing subfloor?

Comment: What is going on top? Ideally the flange goes on the finished surface unless it it a floating material

Comment: It's really not clear what the situation is here--the description isn't very specific. Photos would be priceless. P.S. The shift key is the one that allows capital letters to be typed, such as at the start of sentences. It also helps with question marks.

Comment: What are you referring to by "bracing" There are joists, bridging/blocking between the joists and are not above the joists, subfloor, underlayment and the finish floor. Perhaps a picture would explain a lot....